# How can I click on Primefaces Datatable Table Row with HtmlUnitDriver using Selenium?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, selenium, primefaces

Here is a sample code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class PrimeFaces {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HtmlUnitDriver htmlUnitDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(htmlUnitDriver,10);
        htmlUnitDriver.get("http://primefaces-rocks.appspot.com/ui/datatableComplex.jsf");
        htmlUnitDriver.findElementById("j_idt44:j_idt45_row_0").click();
        WebElement until = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ui-dialog-title-j_idt44:j_idt59")));
    }

}
```

Here, id: **j_idt44:j_idt45_row_0** is for the first row found in this page: http://primefaces-rocks.appspot.com/ui/datatableComplex.jsf

When you click on this row, you will see a window popping up containing an element with id: **j_idt44:j_idt59**

But with HtmlUnitDriver this element is not visible becuase I think either HtmlUnitDriver is not clicking on the row, or the event listener is not being triggered.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: it might be stupid observation but you wrote: "window popping up containing an element with id: j_idt44:j_idt59" btu your code is waiting for id: ui-dialog-title-j_idt44:j_idt59

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a timing problem. I used the following code:

```
driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://primefaces-rocks.appspot.com/ui/datatableComplex.jsf");

driver.findElement(By.id("j_idt44:j_idt45_row_0")).click();
assert driver.findElement(By.id("j_idt44:j_idt59")).isDisplayed();
```

works perfectly fine for me.

Note that with a 10 second timeout, it fails for me every time.

Answer (score 1):

Your id contains a special character : `:`

You have to escape it if you want to access to your div:
`htmlUnitDriver.findElementByCssSelector("#j_idt44\\:j_idt45_row_0").click();`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Strange. Could you share the stack trace ? Did you try with another driver ?

Comment: It says Unable to locate element with ID: j_idt44\:j_idt45_row_0 What other driver can I use?

Comment: You can use the firefox webdriver in order to see th execution and debug easily. But I think I found the issue, could you try:  `htmlUnitDriver.findElementByCssSelector("#j_idt44\\:j_idt45_row_0").click();`

Comment: No does not work.. The problem is I think the request is not made to the server by clicking on the table row..

Comment: Could you share the stack trace? The request is made, I wrote a little test which is clicking on the tr, and the popup appears correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your help and patience, it is here: http://pastebin.com/kdbzG06W This is when I used the CssSelector version.

Comment: So now the issue is on the wait (special char)! `WebElement until = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#ui-dialog-title-j_idt44\\:j_idt59")));` As I said you should debug with firefox driver you'll see the popup opens !

Comment: Firefox works, but the HtmlUnit Driver does not. It says: "Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.selector: ui-dialog-title-j_idt44\:j_idt59" and there is no element by "ui-dialog-title-j_idt44\:j_idt59"

Comment: There are 2 problems:
1) the popup does not have id... so you have to use another selector
2) As you can read https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver: HtmlUnit driver emulate JS but "the results may differ significantly from thos browsers"

Answer (score -1):

I think You should go with similar approach that click on button and wait for execution, but first make sure that you are finding right element.

```
    response_object = htmlUnitDriver.findElementById("j_idt44:j_idt45_row_0").click();
    //test your condition here, and retries until you get the results
    synchronized (respnse_object) {
    page.wait(2000); //wait
    }
```

Comment: What is "page" in here?

Comment: I do not think "        htmlUnitDriver.findElementById("j_idt44:j_idt45_row_0").click();
" is working so no matter how long you wait this will not work.